# Server Render (SSR) One application in Single SPA

Tags: server-side-rendering, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular, single-spa-react

I have below Layout (routes.html) in my Single SPA Application

```
<single-spa-router>
    <redirect from="/" to="/home"></redirect>
  
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper-content">
        <div class="layout-content">
          <application name="@ppbet/layout-app"></application>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="layout-left-content">
            <application name="@ppbet/layout-left"></application>
          </div>
          <div class="center-content">
            <route path="home" exact>
              <application name="@ppbet/home-app"></application>
            </route>
            <div class="main-content-custom">
              <footer>
                <!-- I want this Application to be rendered on Server side -->
                <application name="@ppbet/footer"></application>
              </footer>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="layout-right-content">
            <application name="@ppbet/layout-right"></application>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </single-spa-router>
```

I want the footer Application(A React Component) to be Server Render at the time of load of application.

I have read through [SSR in Single SPA](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ssr-overview) Looks like this to render a whole application on server side and rest of applications on client side. I even tried to use [single-spa-html](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-html-web-components/), But i see this will not render my HTML on Server side. Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am interested, but there are no answers...

Comment: @JavierSedano Unfortunately No. let me know if you find something on this, We are still looking to achive this.